# $p \mid x^2 +n\cdot y^2$ and $\gcd(x,y)=1 \Longleftrightarrow (-n/p) = 1$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a nonzero integer, let $p$ be an odd prime not dividing $n$. then $ p \mid x^2 + n\cdot y^2$ and $x,y$ co-prime  $ \Longleftrightarrow(-n/p) = 1 $

*How can i prove this? by $(-n/p)$ i mean the Legendre symbol.*

For $\implies$ i have already tried this:

$ p \mid x^2 +n\cdot y^2$, so $x^2 + n\cdot y^2 = 0$ mod $p$. then $x^2 = -n\cdot y^2\mod p$...

**So with a little help from my friends this part is done.**

Now how to show the other implication?

Greets
Egon

Comment: Hint: $-ny^2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, so...

Comment: I thought maybe -n must be one then too. But i'm not sure, and i'm just kind of guessing... This is from my lecture notes, and the proof is left to the reader, so i'm not sure i'm even supposed to be able to solve it :)

Comment: Indeed. One way to show $-n$ is one too, is multipling with the inverse of $y^2$ modulo $p$ in your congruency. Edit: looks like someone has already given this hint...

Comment: I had this idea, but i wasn't sure that the inverse of $y^2$ modulo $p$ exists, how do i know that it does?

Comment: Oh and thanks to who ever formatted my question to look nicer :P

Comment: Do you know Bézout's theorem? From that one we have $\text{gcd}(n,y^2)=1=a\cdot p+b\cdot y$ for some integers $a,b$. If you consider this modulo $p$, you've got your inverse of $y$. (And so for $y^2$.)

Comment: How do we know that $n$ and $y$ are co-prime?

Comment: Apologies, It had to be $\text{gcd}(p,y)=1=a\cdot p+b\cdot y$.

Comment: Ah, okay! So if i consider this modulo $p$ then $b$ should be the inverse of $y$

Comment: Indeed, you've got it.

Comment: I wonder though, how can i be sure that $gcd(p,y) = 1$? I know p is prime, but is that sufficient?

Comment: Suppose $gcd(p,y)>1$. Then it must equal $p$, so $p|y$. Then $p^2|y^2$. And since $p^2|x^2+ny^2$, we have $p^2|x^2$, so $p|x$. But this contradicts the fact that $x$ and $y$ had to be co-prime. (Is everything clear, if not I can just make a new answer and repeat everything, maybe that'll help understand better in stead of this endless recommenting.)

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for clearing it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** We have $x^2\equiv -ny^2\pmod{p}$. Multiply both sides by $z^2$, where $z$ is the multiplicative inverse of $y$.

**Detail:** We need to be careful about the statement of the theorem. So we break up the statement and proof into two parts. When we do, we will discover that the result is stated somewhat too informally.

(i) Suppose that $(-n/p)=1$. Then there exist relatively prime integers $x$ and $y$ such that $p$ divides $x^2+ny^2$.

**Proof of (i):** Since $(-n/p)=1$, by part of the definition of quadratic residue, $n$ is not divisible by $p$. Also, there exists an integer $x$ such that $x^2\equiv -n\pmod{n}$. Thus $x^2+n$ is divisible by $p$, and therefore $x^2+ny^2$ is divisible by $p$, with $y=1$. Note that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.

(ii) Suppose there exist relatively prime integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+ny^2$ is divisible by $p$ and $\gcd(x,y)=1$. This is **not** enough to show that $(-n/p)=1$. For example, let $n=3$. $x=3$, and $y=1$. Thus we must assume in addition that $n$ is **not** divisible by $p$. We prove the desired result, with the modification that we add in the condition that $n$ is not divisible by $p$.

**Proof of (ii):** Note that $y$ cannot be divisible by $p$. For if it is, then from $p$ divides $x^2+ny^2$ we conclude that $p$ divides $x^2$. Then $p$ divides $x$, contradicting the fact that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.

Since $y$ is not divisible by $p$, it has a multiplicative inverse modulo $p$. That is, there is a $z$ such that $zy\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Then $x^2z^2+ny^2z^2\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Thus $(xz)^2\equiv -n\pmod{p}$, and the result follows.

**Remark:** The theorem should really be stated like this. Let $p$ be an odd prime, and suppose that (the integer) $n$ is not divisible by $p$. Then $(-n/p)=1$ if and only if there exist relatively prime integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+ny^2$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: You are welcome. It is an often-used trick.

Comment: Just to make sure: is the question asking to find coprime (x, y) s.t. $x^2+ny^2$ is a QR mod p, or to show that for all coprime (x, y), $x^2+ny^2$ is a QR mod p?

Comment: It is asking to show that $-n$ is a QR iff there exist relatively prime integers $x$ and $y$ such that $p$ divides $x^2+ny^2$.